# SQL get rank depending on reputation points

Tags: mysql

How get user rank ordering by reputation points.
'super_admin' and 'staff' roles shouldn't be in the rank.

**MY QUERY:**
When I make my request including all users the ranking is good but
when I make my request excluding users who have the role 'super_admin' and 'staff' the ranking is wrong

```
SELECT u.id, u.rank 
FROM (
      SELECT u.id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank
      FROM users u, (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
      ORDER BY u.reputation DESC, u.register_date ASC
     ) AS u
LEFT JOIN users_role ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
WHERE r.key_role NOT IN ('super_admin','staff')
AND u.id=3
```

**TABLES:**

```
users table

ID    REPUTATION     REGISTERED_DATE
1     6000           2018-05-20 14:15:10
2     20             2018-05-22 14:15:10
3     2000           2018-05-25 14:15:10
4     350            2018-05-27 14:15:10
5     14             2018-05-27 19:15:10
6     0              2018-05-28 14:15:10
7     584            2018-05-29 14:15:10
8     54             2018-05-30 14:15:10


users_roles table

ID    USER_ID        ROLE_ID
1     1              1
2     2              2
3     3              3
4     4              3
5     5              3
6     6              3
7     7              3
8     8              3


roles table

ID    NAME              KEY_ROLE
1     Super Admin       super_admin
2     Staff             staff
3     Registered user   registered_user
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? Make a text formatted result.. Also the table design suggestes a user can have multiple roles what happens if a user has the staff and registered_user role?

Answer (score 1):

Move the sorting to the outer-most query:

(updated)

```
SELECT u.id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank
FROM users u, (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
LEFT JOIN users_role ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
WHERE r.key_role NOT IN ('super_admin','staff')
ORDER BY u.reputation DESC,  u.register_date ASC
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? You'll need to move the "rank" selector outside the query too, if you want it to match the orderering. Also, in your original post you have a WHERE-statement that says `... AND u.id = 3`. I assume this is a leftover from some testing you've done?

Comment: ideally you shouldn't mix the old comma join syntax with the newer syntax on the same SQL execution "level", mixing those old and newer join syntax might cause problems in the optimizer part.. better here is to write `FROM users u CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r` instead off `FROM users u, (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r` .. .

Comment: Still the same issue...user id 3 is ranked 2nd...should be ranked 1st